# can't login to blackberry developer zone id

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, ganymede

I am trying to download the BlackBerry plugin for Eclipse Ganymede. However, It requests for a Developer Zone ID and password. I registered using this link:

https://origin-bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/bdsc/?lang=na#register

However, the registration does not prompt me to enter a user name. I tried logging in with the email and password I provided, but it does not seem to work.

How do I get the the BlackBerry developer Zone ID?

Answer (score 0):

Can you login at the blackberry developer zone site? If you can't you may need to check your email to verify your account (can't remember if this is apart of the process as it's been a while since I registered). Have you emailed the development support at: devsupport@rim.com, they would be the best place to start outside of the documentation for installing and configuring the plug in here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Java+Plug-in+for+Eclipse+(Win)

Comment: I am able to login to the developer's webpage using my email and password, but on eclipse, it does not recognize that. Is the Developer Zone ID something different?

Comment: No according to the docs the registration at the url you entered should be the same ID for Eclipse.

Comment: It may  be something to do with the email address - I battled for days trying to install the update with my company email address. Re-registering on the Blackberry Developer Zone with a gmail address solved it in seconds.